# How to serialize a QJSonObject?

Tags: json, qt5.1

I am new to the JSON and I started experimenting with it, but I couldn't manage to save any of my QJsonObject, or QJsonArrays at all. Did I get it right, if I want to get the Json format of my QjsonObject I have to serialize it?

Basically I want to save in a json file all my QJsonObsject but it's not working, here is my code

```
    QtJson::JsonObject ingredient;
    ingredient["name"] = newIngredient->GetName();
    ingredient["pirce"] = newIngredient->GetPrice();
    ingredient["date"] = newIngredient->GetDate();
    QByteArray data = Json::serialize(ingredient);

    qDebug() >> data;
```

Like I found out there is no more Json, not QJson, so is there any serialize() function what I could use? 
Thanks and sorry if I used the wrong terms, I am learning them yet.

Comment: Your last line ought to read `qDebug() << data;`. Your `>>` operator could be the problem.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use QJsonDocument to serialize/deserialize JSON.  See below:

```
QJsonObject ingredient;
ingredient["name"] = QString("testName");
ingredient["date"] = QString("testDate");

QJsonDocument doc(ingredient);
QByteArray bytes = doc.toJson();

qDebug() << bytes;
```

This snippet will produce the following JSON output:

```
{
"date": "testDate",
"name": "testName"
}
```